# Настройка Tomcat Java

Tags: java, tomcat

Установил сервер Tomcat после переустановки Windows 7, при запуске Java-приложения через Idea отрывается только дефолтная страница Tomcat. Буду благодарен за совет.
[image: томкат]

Comment: По адресу `localhost:port` и должна открываться страница tomcat-а. Для того чтобы открыть приложение нужно обратиться `localhost:port/ContextPath/page.html` (если страница в корне папки).

Comment: Спасибо за совет